# How do I access objects and classes in another file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, file, class

So I just started using JavaScript and am trying to create an object using a Class (or function as I know it's referred to in this language) in a separate file as the one I created the Class in. I am also trying to access said objects from a third file since I don't want all my objects clouding the main body of my code (I am making a lot of objects). So how do I access these objects and classes in other files? I know there is a way to o this in Java, but what about JavaScript?

Comment: You can load the JS files on the HTML page, one by one.

Comment: It depends on your JavaScript environment. The answer will be different if you are using (for instance) Node.js or embeddeding the JS in an HTML document with `<script>` elements.

Answer (score 4):

When adding the Javascript files to your HTML document, make sure the file you created the Class in is listed first.

```
<body>
   <script src="file-where-class-is-created.js"></script>
   <script src="file-where-class-is-accessed.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, followup question my files are saved as .html and not .js. How much difference does this make?

Comment: To clarify, you created the class, the class that you need to be able to access from other files, inside of a script tag in an HTML file?

Comment: Yes, I also did that for the Class objects I wish to create and access in the third file

Comment: As long as the 3rd file is linked to your HTML file below where you wrote the code to create the class, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your environment. Are you using node?

If so, you'll use `require` and `module.exports` statements to respectively load and export variables across files.

E.g., Let's say I have 2 files, `greetings.js` and `main.js`. There is a function within `greetings.js` that I want to access from my `main.js` To do that, I must first export it:

```
// greetings.js

module.exports.sayHello = function() {
  return 'Hello!';
};
```

Then from my `main.js`, I `require` the `greetings.js` file, assigning it to a variable. This allows me to access it as if it's from the same file.

```
// main.js

var greetings = require("./greetings.js");
greetings.sayHello();  // will return 'Hello!'
```

There are many, many other subtleties than in this contrived example, but this is a basic use case in accessing functions across files in node.

Comment: This is a super noob follow up question but what do you mean by Environment? How do I check what environment I'm in?

Comment: Sure no worries. Are you running your JavaScript in the browser or from the command line?

Comment: I'm writing it in Sublime Text editor and opening it in Google Chrome. I have html as the Document Type.

Comment: Ok then ignore my answer and follow the one above :)